# Allowing a User to access .Net WCF service using Windows Authentication mode and Message Level security

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, authorization

I have a WCF service which is to use windows authentication and message level security.The WCF Service will be an intranet service.

What i have to do is to allow a single user say "domain\user1" to access this service?

I want all other users to be denied access.

Comment: How much research have you done on this?  According to this article, netTcpBinding, which by default uses transport level security and Windows authentication, is recommended for intranet scenarios: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx Is there a reason you need to use message level security here?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="DOMAIN\user1" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Does the ordering of the `allow` and `deny` tags matter? (i.e. does `allow` have to come first?)

Comment: Yes, it matters. It uses the first match rule, which rule matches first will be applied

Comment: that is not enough for the WCF. YOu can easily restrict access to Windows users, but there is no o clean direct way to restrict the Windows Users or Groups